# how to store a curve as SVG in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, svg

I have a view controller on which I can draw a curve and later I store the curve as a png on the device using `UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();` But for the scalability factor I need to store it as a SVG. I already store the coordinates of the curve using `touchesMoved` delegate calls but how can I store the same image as SVG?
[image: the viewController for the curve]

Comment: https://cocoapods.org/?q=SVG